# My Site is not working

Tags: linux, vps, nameserver

I have a problem with my VPS setup. My main site is setup and now I have all the files placed in there but couldn't open the site. One thing I noticed awakrdly is when I do the

host miramichionline.com

It gives me an IP which is not the IP of the name servers(ns1.spry.com and ns2.spry.com).

Do we need to have the NS and A records with the same IP address for the site to work properly?

Comment: Can you post the IP address which your A record points to? It should normally be the same as the IP address of your web server. You can probably find the right IP address in your Cpanel.

Comment: My A record is pointed to 209.59.212.85

Comment: I just checked all my other domains parked on the same server. They seems to be working but the main domain is not working. Its weird al the other sites are working expect the main site.

Could anyone guess what would be the problem?

Comment: When I try to visit miramichionline.com, I see the following text: "google-site-verification: googlebc0b184977f17083.html". I am assuming this is a Google site verification file that you uploaded. It looks to me like the browser is getting to your web server but then just not loading the application you expect - does that sound like a correct summary of what is happening?

Comment: Now everything is working fine. I just messed up with my name servers. I just realised it. Thanks for the help Shannon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point the A-records for your domain-name towards the webserver-IP that is hosting the site. Nameservers should also be configured, but since almost every domain-hoster comes with nameservers pre-installed, I doubt that that is the problem.

Maybe you can check what you get when you manually override the DNS-servers.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)